# Creating a named model in Jena

Tags: jena

Given that [this introduction](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/nlp/entry/an_introduction_to_the_jena_api?lang=en) states that using named models is better practice than using the default model, I'm trying to add a named model to a dataset:

```
Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset("MyDataset");
System.out.println(dataset.containsNamedModel("MyNewModel"));
Model MyNewModel = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
dataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);
dataset.addNamedModel("MyNewModel", MyNewModel);
dataset.commit();
System.out.println(dataset.containsNamedModel("MyNewModel"));
```

but this returns

```
false
false
```

(so it's obviously not adding the model!).  I had a look through [the docs](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/index.html), and there is a `createMethod(String name)` [method](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/ModelMaker.html#createModel-java.lang.String-).  I've tried using this, but because it's in an Interface, java complains when I try an instantiate `ModelMaker` (`Cannot instantiate the type ModelMaker`) - and the docs don't show which classes implement which interface.

This leads to a couple of questions:

1. Is it *actually* best practice to use a named model in a dataset, rather than a default model?
2. How do I call the `createModel` method? In the more [verbose documentation](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/model-factory.html) it says that `ModelFactory` contains a method `createFileModelMaker(String)` - but the [`java docs`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/index.html?org/apache/jena/rdf/model/ModelMaker.html) don't mention this method, and trying to call it predictably leads to `The method createFileModelMaker(String) is undefined for the type ModelFactory`!

Answer (score 2):

`MyNewModel` is empty so there is nothing to add. `addNamedModel` means copy in the contents of one graph into a named on in the dataset.

In TDB, a named graph is held as quads (graph, subject, predicate, object). There is no separate graph management.  If there is no quad for the named graph, then it is not in the dataset.

Comment: Is a `named graph` the same as a `named model`?

Comment: Yes. "Model" and "Graph" are pretty much the same thing.  "Model" is the word used in 2004-timescale RDF specs, which si why it's in the API.